# redirect subdomain to folder without changing url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect the www.domain.com to the www folder without changing the url in the address bar (internal redirect), I tried and used the following code but it's not working

I do this to organize my public_html folder

the .htaccess file is in the public_html folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^www/ /www%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```